# Use Digital Persona DLL Library in Linux server

Tags: python, ctypes, digital-persona-sdk

I don't have much experience with Linux OS.

I managed to use ctypes in Python to access a function in Digital Persona SDK DLL file using this code:

```
import ctypes
dpfjDll = ctypes.CDLL("dpfj.dll")
.....
```

Testing of calling the function worked perfectly on my windows machine, but when I deployed the app to our linux server, I got the following error:

```
OSError: dpfj.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what is going on?

Update:
I tried for testing to set the absolute path temporarily for the file, and now I am getting this error message:

```
OSError: /home/......./main/helper/dpfj.dll: invalid ELF header
```

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to open a Windows DLL from Linux?

Comment: No, but I don't know what to do in this case because I don't have experience with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing Digital Persona SDK on our Linux server and used the following code for loading the library:

```
import ctypes
dpfjDll = ctypes.CDLL("libdpfj.so.3.1.0")
```

Comment: Could you share your interface? It looks pretty awesome.

Comment: I don't have a full interface, but this is the link for the compare function in python: https://github.com/adelkhayata/misc/blob/main/digital_persona_python_interface.py

Comment: Many thanks. Have you managed to do the enrolment from Python?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only did the compare, because it is a little bit hard to map python to the DP C library ( I already have enrolment working in our legacy .NET app )